# Entity Framework and 2 associations on the same table. Is it possible?

Tags: entity-framework, database-design

I have 3 tables:

```
Product
Category
ProductCategory
```

when doing entity framework Database First it creates 2 classes.

```
Product {
    int ProductId
    virtual ICollection<Category>
}

Categories {
    int CategoryId
    virtual ICollection<Product>
}
```

this is great.

I want to create a new property on the table ProductCategory, for example, CreateDate

So I will have one more entity (ProductCategory) with the CreateDate property :

```
Product
Category
ProductCategory
```

So far so good, but it removes the navegability from Product to Category and creates the navegability from Product to ProductCategory and then to Category.

I manually changed in model browser and added a new navegability that create the previous behaviour in classes so I ended up with what I want :

```
Product {
    int ProductId
    virtual ICollection<Category>
    ProductCategory
}

Category {
    int CategoryId
    virtual ICollection<Product>
    ProductCategory
}

ProductCageory {
    Product
    Category
}
```

all compiles fine, but when I run the code and update an entity the following error raises :

```
error 3034: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 2445, 2452:
Two entities with possibly different keys are mapped to the same row. 
Ensure these two mapping fragments map both ends of the AssociationSet 
to the corresponding columns.
```

Is there any way to keep my desired scenario (Both navegabilities from Product to ProductCategory and to Category and vice versa) ? If so, how can I get rid of this error ? am I missing mapping something ?

Tryied to be the less verbose possible but I don't mind adding more information or updating the question if anything missing so don't hesitate to ask for more info. Thanks.

Extra: Using MySql 6.8.3 with Entity Framework 6 (latest minus version) Database First using DbContext and T4.

**updated:**

This is what I want to have :

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused with your final design, your basic requirement, product can have many categories and category can be owned by many products?

Comment: @YuliamChandra yes. Many to many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have many to many relationship that can navigate both ways, you should have as follow.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Category> Categories
    {
        get { return (ProductCategories ?? new ProductCategory[0]).Select(pc => pc.Category).ToArray(); }
    }
}
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<Product> Products
    {
        get { return (ProductCategories ?? new ProductCategory[0]).Select(pc => pc.Product).ToArray(); }
    }
}
public class ProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I want to also have in Product class a navigation to ICollection<Category> and in Category a navitagion to ICollection<Product> and that is where I'm asking if it's possible.

Comment: you can just use `product.ProductCategories.Select(pc => pc.Category)` to get all categories in a product

Comment: @Bart, we can just provide property wrapper to get the categories / products, but for setter, it needs more complex logic to add / edit / delete the new / modified / delete missing ProductCategory[ies] in the DbContext